# Create Dynamic image (.gif) through a generic handler

Tags: c#, imagemagick, generic-handler, magicknet

I have already the algorithm created with the library Magick.Net to show a little time counter, however when I request the gif resource through the generic handler returns a static image, but when I check the test file named: "test.gif" the dynamic image works perfect. To explain me better this is the code:

```
MagickImageCollection image = null;
image = ImageRenderMethods.CreateGIF((DateTime)eventDate);

var path = RequestContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("/Content/Images");
path += "\\test.gif";
image.Write(path);

byte[] buffer = image.ToByteArray();
context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
context.Response.Flush();
```

So I want to know why the response of the generic handler is not a .gif dinamic instead the static result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To any wonder how to expose a .gif through a generic handler with [Magick.Net](https://magick.codeplex.com/) you need to pass the [MagickImageCollection](https://magick.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Combining%20images&referringTitle=Documentation) object into a [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) and finally this to Byte Array I.E.:

```
public static MemoryStream GetMemoryStreamResult(MagickImageCollection imageGif)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageGif.Write(ms, MagickFormat.Gif);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return ms;
}
```

and the call something like:

```
 var imageGif = ImageRenderMethods.GetMemoryStreamResult(image);
 byte[] buffer = imageGif.ToArray();
```

Hope this can be useful for somebody.